# Proactive caching vs. nightly cube reprocess

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

I'm working with an SSAS cube that's fully reprocessed every night by an SSIS job.

My current goal is to get data into the cube with less latency, and to do so I'm looking at implementing proactive caching.

Given that proactive caching should update the cube, would there be any benefit to continuing to dump and reprocess the cube periodically, assuming the proactive caching covers everything?